How does Paul know that Satan disguises himself in 2 Corinthians 11:14?
Where does Paul get the tradition that Satan disguises himself as an angel of light?  Paul says this in 2 Corinthians 11 but I don't remember any other passages that claim that Satan disguises himself. In Ezekiel 28, the writer seems to purposefully conflate the king of Tyre with a rebellious Angelic being. I think it's a fair interpretation to say that the rebellious angel is likely the Satan figure, but I'm curious where Paul got the idea that Satan continues to disguise himself. Thanks in advance.

Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for your question and joining the group. Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  If Paul is a prophet of God, could he not have been inspired to write this idea as original?

@Dottard "If Paul is a prophet of God, could he not have been inspired to write this idea as original?" - one could probably apply some variant of that answer to nearly every question on BH. The fact that OP questioned the source of this tradition means they're open to alternatives. and generally speaking, no biblical text is strictly "original". Syncretism is found in literally every corner of every book; eg canaanite/egyptian mythology, greek philosophy, persian exile influences, etc

@AviAvraham If 'generally speaking' no biblical text is strictly 'original' then this may be one of those particular occasions not covered by your expression 'generally'.

@AviAvraham Yes.  There were previously hidden "mysteries" that were revealed to Paul.  (2 Cor 12:1, 2 Cor 12:7, Rom 16:25, Eph 3:3)

The character called "Satan" does not appear as a shapeshifter or disguise himself in earlier canonical Christian or Jewish writings. This aspect of Satan draws from Jewish legends from the Hellenistic period and later, chiefly the Testament of Job and Life of Adam and Eve (Also called Apocalypse of Moses).
Testament portrays Satan as a trickster who is capable of disguises. He tortures Job because he's an idolatrous Egyptian king and disguises himself as a beggar in the story:

4 Then Satan disguised himself as a beggar and knocked heavily at the door, saying to the door-keeper:
"Report to Job and say that I desire to meet him’’ - Testament of Job 2:4-5

Life introduces Satan as the antagonist of the Edenic narrative, and specifically calls him a "deceiver":

Then saith Eve to them: 'Hear all my children and children's children and I will relate to you how the enemy deceived us. Life of Adam and Eve 15:1-2

These Jewish/Christian books are reflective of the Hellenistic period traditions that influenced Paul in 2 Corinthians when talking about Satans powers to disguise himself.


Very useful answer. I'd add that in the Book of Enoch the fallen angel Azazel brings all kinds  of knowledge to humans in order to seduce them. It seems that the name Satan become the primary appellation of the archdemon sometime between the writing of Enoch and the works you describe.


There is no substantiation in this answer to support the surmise that Paul sourced his expression from the claimed sources. What is singularly missing is the collocation 'Angel of Light'.

Thank for the answer. that got to the heart of my question. I didn't remember any explicit biblical references of Satan disguising himself but I figured that Paul was probably leaning on a tradition formed later.

Satan called "Mara" is mentioned at least 615 times in the Buddhist scriptures which pre-date Christianity. https://suttacentral.net/search?query=mara The temptation of Jesus by Satan parallels the temptation by Mara & His Daughters of the Buddha. There are many concepts in Christianity not found in Judaism that are found literally in Buddhism. Job is obviously a post-Exilic text influenced by the exile in Abraham's original homeland of Babylon. Also, at one time (before Christ) Greco-Buddhism (refer to Wikipedia) was a significant phenomena.


Lucifer
Old English Lucifer "Satan," also "morning star, Venus in the morning sky before sunrise," also an epithet or name of Diana, from Latin Lucifer "morning star," noun use of adjective, literally "light-bringing," from lux (genitive lucis) "light" (from PIE root *leuk- "light, brightness") + ferre "to carry, bear," from PIE root *bher- (1) "to carry," also "to bear children." Venus in the evening sky was Hesperus.
Belief that it was the proper name of Satan began with its use in Bible to translate Greek Phosphoros, which translates Hebrew Helel ben Shahar in Isaiah xiv.12 — "How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning!" [KJV] Because of the mention of a fall from Heaven, the verse was interpreted spiritually by Christians as a reference to Satan, even though it is literally a reference to the King of Babylon (see Isaiah xiv.4). Sometimes rendered daystar in later translations.
As "friction match," 1831, short for Lucifer match (1831). Among the 16c. adjectival forms were Luciferian, Luciferine, Luciferous. There was a noted Bishop Lucifer of Cagliari in Sardinia in the 4th century, a strict anti-Arian regarded locally as a saint.
— lucifer | Online Etymology Dictionary (my emphasis)

The name "Lucifer" literally means "light bringing".
From the very beginning, Satan has presented things in a good light, telling Eve that she wouldn't surely die.
He appeared to her as something good and appealing, offering exactly what she wanted.
We can see from the surrounding verses in 2 Corinthians 11 what is meant by "transforms":

13For such are false apostles, deceitful workers, transforming themselves into the apostles of Christ.
14And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into an angel of light.
15Therefore it is no great thing if his ministers also be transformed as the ministers of righteousness; whose end shall be according to their works.

Like Satan, these ministers of false gospels present themselves as if they are God's legitimate agents.
Their "good news" is literally that, things that people will think are good, without considering any of the accompanying side effects and consequences.
Even as early as the time of Paul, people were corrupting Christianity, transforming it into a more appealing false religion.
Matthew 7:15:

Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's clothing, but inwardly they are ravening wolves.

Matthew 24:11:

And many false prophets shall rise, and shall deceive many.

Matthew 24:24:

For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect.

Philippians 3:18–19:

(For many walk, of whom I have told you often, and now tell you even weeping, that they are the enemies of the cross of Christ:
Whose end is destruction, whose God is their belly, and whose glory is in their shame, who mind earthly things.)

2 Peter 2:1–2:

But there were false prophets also among the people, even as there shall be false teachers among you, who privily shall bring in damnable heresies, even denying the Lord that bought them, and bring upon themselves swift destruction.
And many shall follow their pernicious ways; by reason of whom the way of truth shall be evil spoken of.

1 John 4:1:

Beloved, believe not every spirit, but try the spirits whether they are of God: because many false prophets are gone out into the world.


Very informative, thank you.
